# ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 54

Tags: mysql, configuration, remote-access, digital-ocean

So I created a $5 droplet ubuntu-based and installed mysql via

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Then I ran the sudo `mysql_secure_installation` didn't change the password and hit enter to all the other questions.

and then followed the "Configure MySQL to Allow Remote Access" section instructions.

My `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` looks like this now:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
#skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
#skip-networking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = <MY_DROPPLET_IP>
connect_timeout = 100
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#       
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
Then I might have configured something for port 3306 and ip-tables but can't remember what i tis (found on this community as well)
```

However I cannot connect from my computer to the remote database :( because I get the error on the title, I've googled the hell out of it and seems like Im the only person in the world getting the system error: 54 thing.

This is mysql version:
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.47, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

I've also granted full permissions to the root user and some other users (to test)

doing this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'r00t' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and in a naive attempt, I ran the following commands to "open port 3306":

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d <serverip> --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s <serverip> --sport 3306 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

however I still get this error from hell.... :C

also tried to telnet the server and this was what happened:

```
$ echo X | telnet -e X 45.58.41.103 3306
```

resulting in:

```
Telnet escape character is 'X'.
Trying <ip>...
Connected to <ip>
Escape character is 'X'.
```

And now I want to cry :C

I just want to connect to the server via MySQL workbench and deploy the database in a remote server strictly for testing temporary purposes (security is not an issue here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out my firewall was playing with my feelings here.

Adding an exception to the host and port fixed it. First I tried disabling it and it worked, then I elaborated more and added the exception.

Hope this helps someone out there sometime.